Django Forms update exsisting Data in Model with form.save()
I want to validate the form and then:

Override an exsisting row in intuser if a row with samAccountName already exsist.
Create a new intuser object when no intuser with samAccountName exsist.

models.py
class userdb(models.Model):
    samAccountName= models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    givenName= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    surName= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    accountExpires=models.DateField()
    enabled= models.BooleanField()
    lastLogonDate= models.DateField()
    passwordLastSet= models.DateField()
    department=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    usertype=models.CharField(max_length=3)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.samAccountName}"


class intuser(models.Model):
    samAccountName = models.OneToOneField(
        userdb,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    manager= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sosafe=models.IntegerField()


form.py
class intUserInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    manager =forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=userdb.objects.all(),widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-select','data-live-search':'true'}))
    class Meta:
        model=intuser
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets ={
            'sosafe':forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"})
        }          

Views.py
 elif(request.POST["usertypeID"]=="int"):
            intForm=intUserInfoForm(request.POST)
            if intForm.is_valid():
                intForm.save()
                data={
                    "usertype":"int",
                    'form':intForm,
                }
                return render(request,'test.html',data)
            else:
                data={
                    "usertype":"int",
                    'form':intForm,
                }
                return render(request,'test.html',data)

When I try to validate the form with is_valid() the method returns false when a intuser already exsists. This is probably because the OneToOneField in models.py.
How can I validate the data when a intuser already exsists.

I think I found an answer.
I excluded the field from the form so that is_valid() doesn`t validate the field anymore:
forms.py
exclude = ('samAccountName',)

Then I changed the views.py where I add the field to my form again to save it.
views.py
tempform=intForm.save(commit=False)
tempform.samAccountName = userdb.objects.get(samAccountName=request.POST['samAccountName'])
tempform.save()

